# How can I activate RAG with Microsoft Autogen having already my agents with data in them?

Tags: python-3.x, openai-api, pre-trained-model, data-retrieval, azure-openai

I have created an assistant using the OpenAI platform and have successfully integrated it with a set of documents. The document retrieval functionality works as expected in all scenarios except when interfacing with Microsoft Autogen.

I am providing my API key, with the expectation that Microsoft Autogen would seamlessly interact with the OpenAI assistant, accessing the pre-loaded documents. However, this is not happening as anticipated.

Can someone provide insights or solutions for integrating OpenAI's assistant with Microsoft Autogen, especially for document retrieval purposes? Are there specific configurations or steps I am missing to enable this integration?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

In addition to my previous query about integrating OpenAI's assistant with Microsoft Autogen for document retrieval, I've attempted to use some of the configuration options available in Autogen. While I've consulted the Autogen documentation for document retrieval, my goal is to embed the documents directly within the OpenAI/Azure platform, rather than programmatically through code.

Is there a way to directly insert documents into the OpenAI/Azure environment that can be accessed by Autogen without having to handle them in the code? I'm looking for a more streamlined, perhaps GUI-based, method to manage these documents for use with OpenAI's assistant within Microsoft Autogen.

Any advice or steps to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.